# Highchart is not getting resized while print

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, highcharts

Highchart is integrated into `angularjs` directive. The directive only prints the content of an element. Below is the code of directive. Took the code from [Here](https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-angularjs)

```
// if there is no printing section, create one
        if (!printSection) {
            printSection = document.createElement('div');
            printSection.id = 'printSection';
            document.body.appendChild(printSection);
        }

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function () {
                var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(attrs.printElementId);
                if (elemToPrint) {
                    printElement(elemToPrint);
                    // tried to resize chart wich chart.setSize() and it works here
                    window.print();
                }
            });

            window.onafterprint = function () {
                // clean the print section before adding new content
                // when I tried to resize the chart back to normal size, it doesn't work
            }
        }

        function printElement(elem) {
            // clones the element you want to print
            var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
            printSection.appendChild(domClone);
        }

        return {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };
```

Below is the css being used:

```
@media screen {
    #printSection {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media print {
    body * {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    #printSection, #printSection * {
        visibility:visible;
    }
    #printSection {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
    }
}
```

Apart from chart everything is printed correctly on a page. The chart is getting cut on print. As I know highchart is responsive but it is not working properly in print layout.

In `window.onafterprint`, resizing of chart works only for first time. On the subsequent print calls, new chart element is getting added to the dom.

**What am I missing here ? Do I need to resize the chart or to redraw ? And where to resize or redraw it ? Do I need to apply `css` to highchart element ?**

Comment: Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? Have you seen [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821003/redraw-resize-highcharts-when-printing-website)? An another example that might help - http://jsfiddle.net/uzp1vmLb/6/